# Is it faster to upload one big file or more smaller ones?

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

first of all I don't know if question like this already exists, I tried but couldn't find it, so if there is I apologize.

I am trying to stream video by sending each frame to client and then displaying it using Javascript on Website. (so it all works using WebSockets).

I host websocket server on a PC (c# is the language). So, I take screenshot of entire screen and immediately send it over to client.

Now, my question is: should I store multiple frames (say 3?) to one file, then upload that file or should I send frame by frame like I already do? I wonder which one is faster?

Thank you.

Comment: It realy depends how much "per file" overhead there is. | However streaming already dictaties how this needs to be done. Starting with a video file format, that can deal with missing parts or even changing quality levels.

Comment: I would also advice reading the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/ | Usually I tell people to skip part 1, but you definitely need to read it.

Comment: Usually it is preferable to use one big file *instead* of a lot of small files. per file/per request overheads will add up. However with video you **already** have a big file by nature. Splitting it up into smaler files really makes no sense. As @swills044 wrote, the lower network layers will already deal with splitting every big file (and even small files) up into smaler frames, packets, etc. as is deemed usefull. Life streaming is a whole thematic in itself. While non-life streaming is really just "file download".

Answer (score 1):

They are both going to upload the same size of file, one will be split up though so. They should theoretically upload at the same time- this all depends on bandwith also.

Comment: That is not entirely correct but also not entirely wrong. A lot of small files will incur "per file" overheads. Those can go as far as needing completely seperate requests, or just extra headers in the single big file transfer. A single large file will by nature be faster, as it minimizes that overhead. | If that difference is relevant and should be cared for? That is indeed a important question. For that we can just link the speed rant: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that either way they will be split into packets when they cross networks, so it is more about how you would like to deal with the frames on the client side. If I were you I would let the lower technologies handle details like this (e.g the frameworks or libraries you are using) unless you have a specific purpose for sending the frames in intervals because it will add time on to the upload and it adds more room for things to go wrong with separate loads of frames. E.g; you could send the split frames in the wrong order.